App\Application\Command\CreateUserCommand::__construct(): Argument #1 ($id) must be of type Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid, Ramsey\Uuid\Lazy\LazyUuidFromString
I have this controller
<?php

namespace App\Infrastructure\Controller;

use App\Application\Command\CreateUserCommand;
use Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\MessageBusInterface;

class UserController extends AbstractController
{

    public function __construct(private MessageBusInterface $bus){}

    public function createUser(Request $request):JsonResponse
    {

        $data = json_decode($request->getContent(),true);

    
        $userCommand = new CreateUserCommand(
            $id = Uuid::uuid4(),
            $data['email'],
            $data['name'],
            $data['surname'],
            $data['password']
        );
        
        $this->bus->dispatch($userCommand);
        
        return new JsonResponse($data);
    }
}

But I get this error
App\Application\Command\CreateUserCommand::__construct(): Argument #1 ($id) must be of type Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid, Ramsey\Uuid\Lazy\LazyUuidFromString given, called in /var/www/html/src/User/Infrastructure/Controller/UserController.php on line 28

Its suposed that Uuid::uuid4() generates a Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid but its generating a Ramsey\Uuid\Lazy\LazyUuidFromString I haven't changed anything on the config.
Not sure what is wrong on this code or config

They use LazyUuidFromString for performance reasons compare with documentation:

Lazy version of a UUID: its format has not been determined yet, so it is mostly only usable for string/bytes conversion. This object optimizes instantiation, serialization and string conversion time, at the cost of increased overhead for more advanced UUID operations.
Internal: this type is used internally for performance reasons, and is not supposed to be directly referenced in consumer libraries.

Uuid::uuid4() returns an UuidInterface it would be best if you require Ramsey\Uuid\UuidInterface in your CreateUserCommand instead of Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid
